# Using twython to reply to a given tweet

Tags: python, twitter, twython

How can I use twython to post a reply to any twitter id?

The way to post a status update on twitter by this awesome twython library is as follows -

```
    try:
        a = twitter.update_status(status=message)
        return HttpResponse("1", content_type='text/plain')
    except TwythonError as e:
        return HttpResponse(e, content_type='text/plain')
```

Just wanted to know, how can I post a reply to a tweet using twython?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the twitter id, you can simply do add in_reply_to_status to the update_status function.

```
try:
    a = twitter.update_status(status=message, in_reply_to_status_id=twitter_id)
    return HttpResponse("1", content_type='text/plain')
except TwythonError as e:
    return HttpResponse(e, content_type="'text/plain')
```

This can be found [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update).

Also, you should check out the endpoints.py in the twython package for more functions to use Twython.

Comment: It's not enough. You have to start your reply message with the screen name of the user you want to reply to.

Comment: The above is true, but now there is also the option to set `auto_populate_reply_metadata=True` which will automatically append the user of the replied status in the list of replied users (since Twitter now supports implicit list of replied users).